# Force MSBuild to hold reference to binaries

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0

How can I force MSBuild to hold reference to binaries even when they're not referenced in code
?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest using this program on the exe etc [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) this should give you a list of what it need

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem is that I know the dependencies, and it is put them in the bin folder at rebuild action, but not at package function. also calling clean not clear that dependencies.